# Async Task e/ou Aplication

Tags: android

Estou a desenvolver uma `app` que precisa de estar sempre ligada ao servidor. Para isso pensei utilizar uma `async task` para correr em background a ligação ao servidor mas quando mudo de `Activity` a ligação termina.

Estive a ler alguma documentação na internet e percebi que posso fazer com que a ligação ao servidor seja sempre constante através de uma `Aplication`.

O meu problema é que eu não consigo entender qual é a diferença entre `Aplication` e `Async Task`, porque é que as duas podem dar origem ao mesmo resultado ?

Comment: Que eu saiba, a classe `Application` representa seu aplicativo e não oferece nenhum recurso para manter ligação com um servidor. Você não quer dizer `Service`?

Comment: Supostamente podemos ter varias 'Aplication' na nossa App. Eu não entendi muito bem este conceito aplicado à programação em Android é por isso que a minha duvida reside em Aplication ou Async Task.

Comment: Incorreto. Onde você leu isso? `Application` deve ser uma só por app (o `AndroidManifest.xml` só permite registrar uma subclasse de Application no atributo `android:name` do elemento `<application>`, quando essa subclasse existe). Novamente, você não quer dizer `Service`?

Comment: Eu uso e recomendo a biblioteca Volley que é recomendada pela Google. [https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html](http://Volley ) Eu faço uma única instância dela como Aplication. De uma pesquisada sobre.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A classe `Aplication` é como um singleton, é uma para cada aplicação `Android`. Mas ela não foi desenhada para executar tarefas em background e sim para guardar informações em runtime sobre a aplicação.
Como diz no javadoc:

> Application
>
> Classe base para manter o estado da aplicação. Você pode fornecer sua propria implementação especificando no seu AndroidManifest.xml's na tag , isso faz com que sua classe seja instanciada quando o processo da sua aplicação/pacote for criada.
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Já a AsyncTask

> AsyncTask facilita e habilita um uso apropriado da Thread de UI( A Thread que desenha na tela). Esta classe permite executar operações em background e publicar resultados na tela sem ter que manipular Threads e/ou Handlers.

Logo `AsyncTask` faz operações em background para mostrar em algum lugar, e `Application` serve para guardar estados da aplicação.

Nenhuma destas duas combina exatamente com sua necessidade que é executar uma aplicação que esteja sempre conectada ao servidor.

Para isso você precisar utilizar outra estrutura, que é a `Service`.
Você pode obter mais informações sobre services na documentação oficial:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html