# Evitar que o serviço se encerre

Tags: android, android-service

Olá, tenho um aplicativo android que rastreia sinal de gps, funciona normal mas toda vez que ele fica em segundo plano ele fecha sozinho. 
Ja pesquisei sobre o assunto e vi que o android controla o fechamento de aplicativos em segundo plano. 
Existe alguma função que evite isso e mantenha ele sempre aberto?

Comment: Olá. De uma olhada neste post, acho que pode te ajudar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10589/async-task-e-ou-aplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a classe [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) para Android, ela é perfeita para aplicativos que ficam rodando em segundo plano realizando alguma tarefa de tempo em tempo. Você pode utilizar a classe service em conjunto com a classe [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) ou TimerTask. Seu serviço rodando em segundo plano só será terminado pelo Sistema Operacional em casos extremos de necessidade de liberação de recursos, e mesmo que seu serviço pare de executar, quando puder o Android SO reinicia seu Service.